# Is there any country without any embassies?

Tags: foreign-policy

There must be some countries in the world which believe there are no benefits of having an embassy abroad.
Are there?

Edit:

If not, is there a list of countries by number of embassies?

Comment: I imagine the Vatican and other such enclaves don't have any embassies (unless of course you count churches).

Comment: Whilst researching, I found this, which might explain how many enclaves maintain diplomatic relations: *A number of the very small states have diplomatic relations, but the UK is represented by a non-resident Embassy. For example, San Marino does not have a UK Embassy in San Marino itself.  Relations are conducted from the UK Consular office in Florence, Italy.*

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey I think the question is the other way around: About countries which send no embassy anywhere. The Vatican does have something like that (ambassadors are called nuncios). There are many cases of ambassadors to a given country working elsewhere for practical reasons. Examples include embassies covering several countries (some of them much larger than San Marino) or international organisations. Sweden even has some ambassadors working directly from Stockholm, taking a plane when they need to instead of maintaining an actual mission in the receiving country.

Comment: @Festinger There may be some issues here with the definition of "country". Do you have any particular one in mind?

Comment: I mean a recognized country by the UN.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, Wikipedia has lists of countries and their embassies.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_diplomatic_missions

So the answer is no.

There are 2 countries with one embassy, Kiribati and Nauru:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_diplomatic_missions_of_Kiribati

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_diplomatic_missions_of_Nauru

Comment: For completeness, both those countries appear to also have a High Commission (the traditional term for a diplomatic mission between countries in the British Commonwealth, due to the Monarch not sending ambassadors to himself) in Fiji.

Comment: Wikipedia also has this (unsourced) claim, "Kiribati has only three permanent mission abroad, the High Commission in Suva, Fiji, an embassy in Taipei, Republic of China (Taiwan), and a permanent mission to the United Nations in New York. It has honorary consulates in London, Auckland, Sydney, Honolulu, Tokyo, and Hamburg. In Kiribati, there are High Commissions from Australia and New Zealand and embassy of the Republic of China (Taiwan), and the People's Republic of Cuba."

Comment: I suppose three embassies and 6 honorary consuls with a population of 112,000 citizens cost a substantial amount of money.

Comment: @gnasher729: The honorary consuls probably cost the state not much; and I suppose that Taiwan somehow pays for the embassy. Same probably goes for the mission to the United Nations. And the High Commission in Fiji might be somewhat funded by the British Commonwealth. OTOH Liechtenstein has only 37000 citizens and is quite rich. :-)